# Unit ball for a special norm

Tags: normed-spaces

What does the unit sphere for the norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\displaystyle N(x,y)\rightarrow\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{|x+ty|}{t^2+t+1}$, look like ?

---

My approach was to consider $y=ax$ so as to get $f(y)=|x|\dfrac{|1+aw|}{t^2+t+1}$ then study the variations of this function wrt $t$ and hence deduce the points on the line $y=ax$ where the norm is $1$. By doing this for all lines that would have given me the whole unit ball. However, with this method, I encounter a determinant $5a^2-2a+1$ which would require branching many cases, hence I don't think that's the way to go.

Comment: Have you tried to express $N(x,y)$ in close form?

Comment: @Surb I haven't managed to find a better form for $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$(x,y)\in B(0,1)\iff N(x,y)=\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{|x+ty|}{t^2+t+1}\le1\iff |x+ty|\le t^2+t+1, \forall t\in\Bbb R\\\iff -t^2-t-1\le x+ty\le t^2+t+1,\forall t$$

the second inequality gives

$$t^2+(1-y)t+1-x\ge0,\forall t\iff \Delta_2=(1-y)^2+4x-4\le0$$
and the first inequality give
$$t^2+(1+y)t+x+1\ge0,\forall t\iff \Delta_1=(1+y)^2-4x-4\le0$$
hence the unit ball is the set of point $(x,y)$ satisfying
$$\Delta_1\le0\quad;\quad \Delta_2\le0$$

We plot the unit ball using Walfram alpha

[image]

Comment: I am searching for a way to get this curve "by hand", is $(1+y)^2-4x-4\le0$ a known type of curves ?

Comment: It's a branch of an hyperbole.